# Change .htaccess for new permanent link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a page like this link: `www.mysite/lab/index.php?pagina=blablabla`

I used `.htaccess` with this settings:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-Z0-9]+)$ ./index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I go on `www.mysite/lab/blablabla` I don't see my page but I've error `page not found`

I've page in `www.mysite/lab/` and other 3 folders, can I use ELSE IF in .htaccess?

Comment: What does not work exactly? What error do you get? The only fault I see right now, is that there are 2 equality signs in the RewriteRule, but it should rewrite the request...

Comment: "It doesn't work" as in how exactly it doesn't work? Is the double equal sign at `?pagina==$1` intentional?

Comment: It's a mistake to write here! In my file there is only one!

Comment: Error is that if I go on www.mysite/lab/blablabla I don't see my page

Comment: Do you want to have only one htaccess file to handle those 4 folders ? In that case, your htaccess would be located in root folder. Otherwise, you can have 4 different htaccess (one for each folder) with almost the same code

Comment: I would like to have only one htaccess! Can you help me with code! It doesn't work :(

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer as soon as you give me an example for other 3 folders. What would be the url and what would be the file to rewrite to ?

Comment: this is my folders in www.mysite/: lab || blog || faq || presentazione || feed || editori

Comment: Do you want a rewrite for all those folders ? Do they all have an `index.php` file to rewrite to ?

Comment: I would like to have from **www.mysite/lab/index.php?pagina=**blablabla to **www.mysite/lab/**blablabla. This for all folders :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only one `htaccess` to handle all your concerned folders, you can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(lab|blog|faq|presentazione|feed|editori)/([^/]+)$ $1/index.php?pagina=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I put my .htaccess in root folder?

Comment: Yes in the document root folder (where your domain is pointing to)

Comment: I put in my root folder and in localhost I can't see new permalink :( I see my site from `127.0.0.1/mysite/lab/index.php?pagina=blablabla` and if i go in `127.0.0.1/mysite/lab/blablabla` tell me _page not found_

Comment: That's because you are in a subfolder `mysite`. I edited my answer taking your comment into consideration. But now, you have to put the htaccess in `mysite` folder instead of `root` folder

Comment: Did you enable *mod_rewrite* and allow `htaccess` in your apache configuration ? Did you replace `mysite` (`RewriteBase` line) by your real subfolder name ?

Comment: Yes, I replace `myste` with real name but I don't know how to enable mod_rewrite in apache configuration.. sorry nut can you tell me? :(

Comment: allow htaccess where I can find it?

Comment: Find your Apache configuration file. Should be in `conf/httpd.conf` under Apache folder (since you're using it as localhost). Then, check if `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for your root folder (in a `Directory` block). Also, check if `LoadModule` line (for `rewrite` -> `mod_rewrite`) has a hastag `#` before it. If that's the case, remove leading `#`. Then restart your server

Comment: Ok, in my Apache configuration I have
`<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>`
and in `LoadModule` in line that you tell me I don't have before `#`.
In my site function in site of my friend none, and we have the same configuration :(

Comment: This is the line: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. Make sure it has no leading `#`. Then, this is not about `<Directory />` block but next one (i assume the one for your main/root folder)

Comment: Yes this line don't have before `#` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69662/discussion-between-justin-iurman-and-principedade).

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is taking the whole request path and using it as a parameter for `$1`. You only need to capture content right of the last slash, not the whole path.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule /lab/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
```

You can additionally use `RewriteBase` to specify the base for your rewrites which essentially allows you to skip the `/lab/` part.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lab/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: With this i've a `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: I've page to rewrite in myste/lab and in other 3 folders..can I use ELSE IF in htaccess?

Comment: Try editing your rewrite rule so that the second range in the group contains only small letters. In other words change `[A-Za-Z0-9]` to `[A-Za-z0-9]` If that doesn't work check the web server logs to see what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're denying the `/` from the regexp. You either need to do what holodoc said, or modify the regexp to

`^([A-Za-Z0-9/]+)$`

Comment: That's a good solution for the problem. Anyway, you don't need to escape the slash